# append new info into an array using merge

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, merge

i am trying to append a new value to an already existing array in my target table by using the merge strategy of bigquery. basically if i have this example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_test`
( 
global_entity_id STRING,
customer_id STRING,
associated_customers ARRAY<STRING>
)
CLUSTER BY global_entity_id;

INSERT INTO `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_test`
(global_entity_id, customer_id, associated_customers)
 VALUES
('FP_DE', 'lucas', ['vlad', 'katya']);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_source`
(
global_entity_id STRING,
customer_id STRING,
associated_customers ARRAY<STRING>
)
CLUSTER BY global_entity_id;

INSERT INTO `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_source`
(global_entity_id, customer_id, associated_customers)
VALUES
('FP_DE', 'lucas', ['calin']);
```

I want that the final table has

ONE record, with the array ['vlad', 'katya', 'calin']

the merge strategy schema looks like this but i am not sure which one to use

```
MERGE
 `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_test` AS target_table
USING (
 SELECT
   *
 FROM `XXX.temp.associated_lucas_source`

 ) source_table
ON
  ("not sure")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below as a direction

```
MERGE `XXX-temp-associated_lucas_test` AS t
USING (SELECT * FROM `XXX-temp-associated_lucas_source`) s
ON true
WHEN MATCHED 
AND t.global_entity_id = s.global_entity_id 
AND t.customer_id = s.customer_id THEN
  UPDATE SET associated_customers = ARRAY_CONCAT(t.associated_customers, s.associated_customers);
```

resulted in below

[image]

Comment: and  if i want to also add in the on a ON FALSE WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW, how it would be the best way?

Comment: your initial question allow2ed to use `ON true` trick! but if you want multiple conditions to be checked  - you need to provide specific match criteria `t.global_entity_id = s.global_entity_id 
AND t.customer_id = s.customer_id` instead of `true` and then define MATCH and NON MATCH actions

Comment: hope you can make it - if not  - post new question with relevant details, so we can help you further :o)

Comment: perfect, got it 100%. it worked, thanks

Comment: if i want to add also a insert condition for a new record not present in test but yes in source into test? how i should do it (i want to keep also the other logic)